# Getting the SharePoint logo from Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, team-sites, microsoft-graph, site-logo

How could I get the SharePoint site logo from the Graph API?

With the SharePoint site logo I mean this:

[image]

Inside the documentation I didn't found anything that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Microsoft Graph [site resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation, there is no property available for accessing SharePoint site logo.

---

**Additional info**:

Instead of using Microsoft Graph, try using the URL in below format to get the site logo URL:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/siteiconmanager/getsitelogo?type='1'
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I've found this one to but don't know that it would be possible to get the image from that URL using a Graph access token.

Comment: Are you showing the image somewhere in your application? If yes, what happens if you build `img` with URL in above format (similar HTML as given in above image)?

Comment: That only works if you have a current logged in browser session 